# Error on compiling a grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm having a strange issue with getting my GridView - RowDataBound
method to compile. I've got a simple GridView with the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_View_Documents" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" 
  DataKeyNames="DocumentName,Description" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
  OnSorting="gv_View_Documents_Sorting" OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_View_Documents_RowCancelingEdit"  
  OnRowDataBound="gv_View_Documents_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="gv_View_Documents_RowEditing" 
  OnRowUpdating="gv_View_Documents_RowUpdating">
```

When I compile, it shows an error shown below.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No
>   overload for
>   'gv_View_Documents_RowDataBound'
>   matches delegate
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventHandler'

I have a similar setup for another grid view  with no compile
issues.

Any ideas? I'm working with C# and ASP.NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably your event handler method signature does not match with GridViewRowEventHandler signature i.e.

```
public delegate void GridViewRowEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    GridViewRowEventArgs e
)
```

Most probably, you may have used EventArgs as a parameter in your event handler.

Comment: yes, i am using eventargs as a parameter. how can i solve this. i have another similar grid view. there is no compilation error with that.

Comment: @Shameer, your event handler signature is wrong. It should be protected void gv_View_Documents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) { } - note you are using GridViewCommandEventArgs instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you dont have a method (in a code behind) with params: Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e

```
 void gv_View_Documents_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

Comment: i already have such a code behind function  -> protected void gv_View_Documents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {      }